# Migrating server configuration to new machine

Tags: server, transfer, migration

I have a VServer (Ubuntu 14.04) with some problems, where reinstalling the OS was suggested here and also by the hoster.

I was planing to clone all the configuration, installed packages etc. except the few faulty ones of course. I found a lot of instruction how to migrate different parts of the OS but no full how to/script. Since I'm very suprised about this fact I was wondering if somebody knows one.

It should include:

- users
- home
- /etc
- installed
- packages
- /var/www
- /var/vmail
- /opt
- databases: mysql and postgresql
- etc.

limitations are:

- the servers do not have the same hardware
- i can't install packages on the source system
- only ssh access

Comment: What do you mean by "VServer"? is it a virtual machine in, say, VMWare? Or does that mean something else?

Comment: Don't. Really. Don't. "users" and "home" recreate them on the new server. Same for /etc, /opt packages and configs for packages. Do make a dump of your databases (mysqldump and pg_dump/pg_restore).  /var/www will be a tar file and an scp, /var/vmail is not a normal dir so that one is up to you.  Copying will also copy any problems into your new setup. Plus I would also assume you would start using 16.04 and not 14.04. Take the time to do the setup again, this time do a better job than the 1st time and document it.

Comment: "I found a lot of instruction how to migrate different parts of the OS but no full how to/script" That's because it is a bad idea ;-) Scripts tend to assume things and expect things to be set up a certain way. If you want a script it will be one for you and you alone.

Comment: @JDS yes the VServer is a virtual machine. I don't know which technique they use.

Comment: @Rinzwind you are right but I'm afraid to miss out configurations or the problem is that I copied most of etc and have troubles now again. Setting up the services was a pain and I would prefer to not do it again especially because we should have no downtime.

Answer (score 2):

Out of my several years experiences with real hardware or cloud instances I would recommend you to not try to copy configuration from old installation unless it is something really specific.

Also now on 2016/12 I would not recommend you to stay on Ubuntu 14.04 unless you have something really hardly depending on this version.

I have "basic scripts" for different types of instances including all basic packages and settings I need - something like "Dockerfile" with all installation steps. It includes "must have" packages and it ensures you have stable environment when you create new machine.

Only case when I really clone existing instance is new mysql replica on GCE because it saves a lot of time and all replicas are supposed to be the same.

So as stupid as it sounds I would recommend you to "create machine from scratches". Because if you cannot solve problems on old machine it is very likely you could at the end duplicate at least some problems together with old configuration.

And one more thing - it is generally not exactly good idea to run mysql and postgresql on one machine or instance unless those are very small and not heavily used databases. Both databases have quite a different strategies for work with memory and disks and to get good performance from both databases you would need to fiddle a bit with their settings.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem with the two database services, I did not know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning an entire server isn't usually the right approach. That just clones all the problems. The approach typically taken is as follows

- Build new server
- Install required software
- Clone data

If you want to be able to manage the configuration of this and other servers, long term, at scale, and be able to quickly migrate the whole thing to a new system when the need arises, I highly recommend a modern configuration management tool that is designed to automate the deploy and build of a new server. Chef, Puppet, and Ansible come to mind. But I recommend Ansible because of it's ease of use and it's agentless operation.

There are some important details missing from your question, such as if this is a VM hosted somewhere, what software is installed, how the server is used. These details may require one to change one's approach to building a new system.

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla does the job, connect your new machine HDD via USB then bootup via clonezilla CD follow instructions too clone the source HDD to the external USB. be careful and make sure you cloning the right HDD to the right source. after completion of clone insert your HDD to the new machine.